# select random p-node via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Someone got a nice code snippet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
//generate random number with maximum size of the number of p elements
var elems = $('p');
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * elems.length);
alert(elems.eq(rand).text());
```

Comment: Note this will give you a dom node and not a jquery object. For a jq object use $('p').eq(rand);

Comment: You might want to change this to only look up the elements once.  Also, no need for parseInt.  Length is already an integer.  Random also is open ended (< 1, not <= 1) so your first version using length itself was correct.

Comment: @tvanfosson - Thanks. Removed parseInt, and length -1, but I don't get what you said about '...look up the elements once'.

Comment: I edited your question.  I just meant that you could store the results of the $ function in a variable and reuse it instead of running the function each time to get the collection.

Comment: @tvanfosson - I get you now :)